# Cannot setup gsutil on Ubuntu, where is the project number for an Android app?

Tags: android, gsutil

I followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install but I cannot run gsutil from any dir. I have gsutil in /home/myname/gsutil/.

Then I tried to install with apt-get and get this message when I run:

Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::UserAgent module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/bin/gsutil line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/gsutil line 26.

Then I tried to run python gsutil.py config and I get asked for my project number on the Google developer console but I have no project there since this is an Android app. Where do I find this project number then?

Will I setup my authentication in the config step too?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you don't have gsutil in your path. Try this:

```
echo export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/gsutil >> ~/.bashrc
```

Installing gsutil via apt-get doesn't work, you wind up installing a different tool also named gsutil (by GrandStream BudgeTone).

For other people who might have landed here after attempting to install via apt-get (as I did), you can properly install gsutil via your terminal like this:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/pub/gsutil.tar.gz
tar xfz gsutil.tar.gz -C $HOME
echo export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/gsutil >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I'm trying to build one of lib project [LinPhone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android) and it giving me **Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::UserAgent module)** ...any suggestion here ?

Comment: Follow this link to install it should resolve your problem: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install